# Multiline equation inside a split environment

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have a series of equations aligned at `=` inside a `split` environment.  (They're all actually the same equation, so the left-hand-side is missing in all but the first equation.)

Unfortunately the last equation is super long and doesn't fit into a single line.  It needs to be split.  I don't what the convention is, but I'd say it should be right-aligned.  How do you do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
  &= b + b + b + b \\
  &= c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
% obviously does not work
  \hfill + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c 
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `multlined` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
    &= b + b + b + b \\
    &= \!\begin{multlined}[t]
       c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
         + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
     \end{multlined}
   \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output 1]

Note: the `\!` before the environment is to get correct spacing between `=` and `c`.

It's also possible to specify the total width of the two lines (from left margin at first line to right margin at last line) as an optional argument to `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
    &= b + b + b + b \\
    &= \!\begin{multlined}[t][10cm]
       c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
         + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
     \end{multlined}
   \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output 2]

If you want the two lines right aligned, you can set the `mathtools` key `firstline-afterskip` to `0pt`, either globally or locally:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\mathtoolsset{firstline-afterskip=0pt}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
    &= b + b + b + b \\
    &= \!\begin{multlined}[t]
       c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
         + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
     \end{multlined}
   \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output 3]

Answer (score 4):

The standard and easiest method is to just add a line to the `split` and move right by, say, one quad. This is the method I'd prefer, not bothering about alignment.

Alternatively, use `multlined` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
x &= a + a \\
  &= b + b + b + b \\
  &= c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
  &\qquad + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
\end{split}
\]
\[
\begin{split}
x &= a + a \\
  &= b + b + b + b \\
  &= \mathtoolsset{firstline-afterskip=0pt}
     \!\begin{multlined}[t] % <---- don't forget \!
     c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c \\
       + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
     \end{multlined}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `\!` before `\begin{multlined}` to get correct spacing?

Comment: @hooy Yes! I falsely believed that `mathtools` didn't follow `amsmath` in this respect. Fixed.

Comment: @egreg -- and why are you loading both `amsmath` and `mathtools`?  since `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, that is sufficient.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If the user doesn't want the second solution, also `mathtools` might be unwanted. And I prefer to load both in any case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a stack, for example.  If the line heights were uniform, this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
  &= b + b + b + b \\
  &= \stackengine{\baselineskip}{c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c}
  {{}+ c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c}{U}{r}{F}{F}{L}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the stacked rows were of non-standard heights, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
  x &= a + a \\
  &= b + b + b + b \\
  &= \stackengine{5pt}{c + c + c + c + \dfrac{a}{b} + c + c + c + c + c + c + c}
  {{}+ c + \dfrac{c}{d} + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c}{U}{r}{F}{F}{S}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is the 5th argument of `\stackengine`, given by `{r}` that defines the alignment of the stack.  Other options are `{l}` and `{c}`.